# Regex capture rest of sentance after last match

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Say I have a sentence where I would like to match (and eventually replace but that is not part of the question) certain markers based on what they look like:

`The quick brown fox {NUM} jumped over {211NUM} the lazy dog {NUM}.  The Quick brown fox {NUM10} jumped over the lazy dog.`

I would like to replace the `{NUM}`, `{#NUM}` and `{NUM#}` parts based on logic and the number in the `#`.  And then put it all back together as a single string.

I came up with

`(.*?)({NUM}|{\d*NUM}|{NUM\d*})`

which will obtain the captures I would like, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the REMAINING part of the sentence after the last match, i.e. `jumped over the lazy dog.`

I thought maybe adding `(.*?)` to the end would do it but it does not.  Here is what I have working:

https://regex101.com/r/HpIcAa/1

Comment: What is the programming language? In most cases, just split with `(\{\d*NUM})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  The language is c#, I have added the tag.  Yes, the `(\{\d*NUM})` does match the parts.  But the last part does not get added to a capture group.  I updated the question as I mistakenly put in the wrong part that remains after it.

Comment: Then you just need `Regex.Replace` with a match evaluator as shown below (it can be a lambda if the manipulation is simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to trash garbage collector with split/concating strings. Replace works good, no memory spikes, fast, accept functions as argument too:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pattern = @"(?<num>\{((?<n1>\d+)?NUM|NUM(?<n2>\d+))\})";
        var regx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var input =
            @"The quick brown fox {NUM} jumped over {211NUM} the lazy dog {NUM}.  The Quick brown fox {NUM10} jumped over the lazy dog. ";

        var output = regx.Replace(input, ToReplaceMatch);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    private static string ToReplaceMatch(Match match)
    {
        if (match.Groups["num"].Success)
        {
            var num = int.TryParse(match.Groups["n1"].Value ?? match.Groups["n2"].Value, out var res)
                ? res
                : (int?)null;
            return ToReplaceNum(num);
        }

        return match.Value;
    }

    private static string ToReplaceNum(int? number)
    {
        return "FOOBAR" + (number ?? 0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The quick brown fox FOOBAR0 jumped over FOOBAR211 the lazy dog FOOBAR0.  The Quick brown fox FOOBAR0 jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: Thanks!  I get what you mean by the replace being more efficient and was ultimately the way I was thinking of going.  But I am curios how to get the expression to capture that remaining part of the sentence.

Comment: Add `(?<tail>.+$)?` at the end of expression, access it through "tail", replace it if needed, leave it be if not needed.

Comment: Thanks @eocron.  I tried something like that originally but it did not capture it correctly, at least not in the regex101 link I provided above.  It ends up back tracking to the first `{NUM}` in the line.  This was what motivated me to post the question...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to match only your keywords using this regex pattern: `(?<g1>{NUM})|(?<g2>{\d*NUM})|(?<g3>{NUM\d*})`

Then using [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) function to replace keywords based on your logic.

```
string pattern = @"(?<g1>{NUM})|(?<g2>{\d*NUM})|(?<g3>{NUM\d*})";
string input = "The quick brown fox {NUM} jumped over {211NUM} the lazy dog {NUM}.  The Quick brown fox {NUM10} jumped over the lazy dog. ";
output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, delegate(Match match)
{
    if (match.Groups["g1"].Success)
    {
       return "{Group 1}";
    }
    if (match.Groups["g2"].Success)
    {
       return "{Group 2}";
    }
    if (match.Groups["g3"].Success)
    {
       return "{Group 3}";
    }
    return match.Value;
});
```

See demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1wq4QZ)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I like the conciseness to it.